# Center composable in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Older versions of Jetpack compose `dev-0.x` used to have a `Center` composable to center a widget.

However, in the `alpha` version it has been removed and no specific composable made to handle this task.

In  my case I want to show a progress indicator at the center until data is fetched:

```kotlin
Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
    val state = viewModel.userState
    if (state == null) {
        CircularProgressIndicator()
    } else {
        UserDigest(state = state)
    }
}
```

The result is obviously something like this:

[image]

And the indicator is at the corner.

---

Adding `fillMaxSize()` to the Indicator does not help either:

```kotlin
CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
```

[image]

So, how do I move it (generally a `composable`) to the center of an area?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You have to use a parent container.
For example:

```
Box(
   contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
   modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize() 
) {
    CircularProgressIndicator()
}
```

or:

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    CircularProgressIndicator()
}
```

[image]

Comment: In compose 1.0.0-beta01 Box `alignment` is undefined. Using `contentAlignment` seems to work all the same. So many different ways of trying to do the same seemingly simple thing 

Comment: @VictorUde thanks for feedback. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

There is an even simpler solution without nesting:

```
@Composable
fun CenteredCircularProgressIndicator() = CircularProgressIndicator(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
)
```